# how to import PlayLogback in build.sbt with playframework

Tags: playframework, log4j2

I use Play Framework 2.4 and want to use `log4j2` for logging. To do this, I should `disablePlugins(PlayLogback)` in  `build.sbt` but I got following error:

> build.sbt:10: error: not found: value PlayLogback lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).disablePlugins(PlayLogback)

How to import `PlayLogback` in `build.sbt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im affraid you are not able use custom logging framework in Play 2.4

> Many of our users want to use their own choice of logging framework
>   but this was not possible until Play 2.5.

[Source](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Highlights25#Support-for-other-logging-frameworks)

Comment: That`s right! I upgraded to Play Framework 2.5 then PlayJava and PlayLogback are detected in build.sbt without the need to import them. Thank you.